# ActionBar tabs misplaced in portrait using AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I started using `Theme.AppCompat` in my styles and it broke the tab placement. I'm using the old hack to force tabs on the `ActionBar` in portrait mode:

```
try {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        final Method setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod = actionBar.getClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod("setHasEmbeddedTabs", boolean.class);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setHasEmbeddedTabsMethod.invoke(actionBar, true);
    }
} catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here are screenshots from both portrait- and landscape-orientations:

Portrait - Misplaced:
[image: portrait - misplaced]

Landscape - Correct:
[image: landscape - correct]

Has anyone had similar issues? Is this just a styling issue, or is the `ActionBar` implementation of `ActionBarActivity` the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go without an ActionBar and use a ToolBar instead.  ActionBar deprecated tab support and ToolBar requires no hacks, so it was a sensible solution.